# Add filename in a pdf document

Tags: pdf

I have hundreds of pdf documents to print. I would like to add the filename of the document on the top. I do not care this is done inside the document or if it is just added when printing. 
I did find how to add page numbers...however I am unable to translate this solution to my needs.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated - and they would save my day.

Comment: From Unix and Linux Stack Exchange https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291596/how-to-merge-pdf-file-so-that-each-file-starts-with-file-name

Comment: I tried the solution, but got a lot of errors, that I do not really understand...

Comment: declare -a files del; i=1; for file in *.pdf; do echo -e '.ft H\n.ps 30\n.vs 35\n.sp 10c\n.ce\n'" $file" |groff -Tps |ps2pdf - - >/tmp/title$i.pdf ; files+=(/tmp/title$i.pdf "$file") ; del+=(/tmp/title$i.pdf) ; let i=i+1; done; pdfconcat -o /tmp/out.pdf "${files[@]}"; rm ${del[@]}

Comment: troff: <standard input>:6: warning [p 1, 4.4i]: cannot adjust line
troff: <standard input>:6: warning [p 1, 3.9i]: cannot adjust line
Input PDF (/tmp/title1.pdf): filesize=4312, xrefc=14, xreftc=1, catalogofs=428, #pages=1, is_binary=1
Input PDF (1098823913.pdf): filesize=34953, xrefc=63, xreftc=2, catalogofs=747, #pages=7, is_binary=1
Input PDF (/tmp/title2.pdf): filesize=5186, xrefc=14, xreftc=1, catalogofs=500, #pages=1, is_binary=1
pdfconcat: error at 20118122702 -2018121702 248,04 - 31.14  DHL express ZQL0032458.pdf:141912: trailer expected

Comment: troff: <standard input>:6: warning [p 1, 3.9i]: cannot adjust line
troff: <standard input>:6: warning [p 1, 4.4i]: cannot adjust line
troff: <standard input>:6: warning [p 1, 4.9i]: cannot adjust line
troff: <standard input>:6: warning [p 1, 4.4i]: cannot adjust line
troff: <standard input>:6: warning [p 1, 4.4i]: cannot adjust line
troff: <standard input>:6: warning [p 1, 4.9i]: cannot adjust line

Comment: It looks like you posted the results of a test in comments. Since comments destroy white space these are very hard to read. Things like this are best stored online somewhere and linked to here. pastebin is good and I think there's even an Ubuntu-specific one that I can't find at the moment.

Comment: A quick search turned this up. http://jpdftweak.sourceforge.net . Using it wasn't obvious. The watermark tab lets you add page numbers and the page number tab lets you specify them. It has a batch mode that I didn't try. BTW, it's a tar bomb, so unzip it in an empty directory.

Comment: Just looked again and it doesn't seem to have a file name option.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a script to print all the PDF files in a directory you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.pdf
do
echo "$f" | lpr
lp -o job-sheets=none "$f"
done
```

It isn't pretty, but it will begin each pdf file with a page containing the filename. This doesn't require you to troubleshoot what's going wrong with `groff` but as I said, it's ugly. You could experiment with adding newlines and spaces to push the filename into the center of the first page, and if your printer supports it, even use [ESC/P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESC/P) codes to bold the print.

I still think the [groff solution mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291596/how-to-merge-pdf-file-so-that-each-file-starts-with-file-name) by [Graham](https://askubuntu.com/users/307670/graham) in the comments is superior but this is an alternate solution, free of typos.

Note: Requires a printer set to default. I used the System-wide default for testing.